# Test React component method with setInterval

Tags: reactjs, testing, sinon, enzyme

I am using tape, enzyme, jsdom and sinon for my testing purposes. I wanna test the simple thing, that the state was changed after calling the method.

```
class Countdown extends Component {
      state = {
        count: 0,
        countdownStatus: 'stopped'
      }

      componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
       if (this.state.countdownStatus !== prevState.countdownStatus) {
         switch (this.state.countdownStatus) {
           case 'started':
             this.startTimer()
             break
          }
        }
      }

     startTimer = () => {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
          const newCount = this.state.count - 1
          this.setState({
            count: newCount >= 0 ? newCount : 0
          })
        }, 1000)
      }

      handleSetCountdown = (seconds) => {
        this.setState({
          count: seconds,
          countdownStatus: 'started'
        })
      }

      render () {
        const {count} = this.state
        return (
          <div>
            <Clock totalSeconds={count} />
            <CountdownForm onSetCountdown={this.handleSetCountdown} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Countdown
```

And this is not working. It says that it passes but then my last test always hangs for some reason, all test passes but they don't exit. Maybe it is because of setInterval although I don't test it.

```
test('Countdown =>  should set state to 10, (t) => {
  t.plan(1)
  const wrapper = shallow(<Countdown />)
  wrapper.instance().handleSetCountdown(10)
  wrapper.update()
  t.equal(wrapper.state().count, 10)
})
```

**EDIT:** Ok, i figured it down. The tests are not ending because of setInterval. How would I fix this?

**EDIT 2:** The solution was pretty simple. I just added

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers()
```

and all test finish like they should.

Comment: you can (and should) use Sinon's fake timer: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/fake-timers/

Comment: Thanks Patrick. It works.  I just added var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers() and all test end like they should. You wrote in comments so I can not accept your answer as solution. I will update my question for others to see.

Comment: Glad to help. You could write your own answer with the code that fixed it, that would be ideal for documentation purposes (and you'll even get a badge for that ☺️)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this problem was simple. Using sinon fake timers sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/fake-timers Causes Sinon to replace the global setTimeout so tests can finish

```
test('Countdown =>  should set state to 10', (t: Object) => {
  t.plan(1)
  const wrapper: Object = shallow(<Countdown />)
  /* Causes Sinon to replace the global setTimeout so tests can finish */
  const clock = sinon.useFakeTimers()
  const instance = wrapper.instance()
  instance.handleSetCountdown(10)
  t.equal(wrapper.state().count, 10)
})
```